# Where smallInteger equal to string return result

Tags: mysql, sql, database, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have a table with smallInteger column, with 2 records as zero value.

If I run below query the result is returned:

```
select `status` from users where `status` = 'confirmed'
```

How is possible?

[image]

Actually any string return this records.

Comment: A non-numeric string can only be cast to 0. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Study carefully: [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  Functions and Operators  /  Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql will cast the `CHAR` value to `SMALLINT`, since `'confirmed'` is not numeric it will return `0`

so this: `0 = 'confirmed'` gets interpreted as this `0 = CAST('confirmed as SMALLINT)`' which evaluates as `0 = 0`

so when the column `status` is `0` it's equal to `'confirmed'` as a `SMALLINT`